# How to set up server on Ubuntu 18.04 desktop?

Tags: server

I am trying to set up a server on Ubuntu Desktop 18.04 for a school project...I have tried installing multiple different apps to create a server (ftp), but all have failed installing. Ethernet is also not connecting...

Comment: Please [edit] and add more details. What apps have you tried installing, and what errors did you get? What happens when you try to connect ethernet? Post any error messages in full.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, if you don't have internet, you're gonna have a hard time doing anything on the internet. Unless you have some exotic unsupported ethernet card, it's unlikely that ubuntu is the issue.

Second of all, you seem unsure about what a server is. A server is just a computer running a piece of software (or often the term just refers to the software) to serve a specific kind of program as a client. You can't use an ftp server to play minecraft on it, an ftp server is only for ftp (filesharing). Also ftp is just a protocol, not a program.

Try this to install an ftp server, it should be installing. Maybe you forgot to run as root.

```
sudo apt install vsftpd
```

If the server should be public, you'd have to let your computer run 24/7, open up a port on your router and maybe buy a domain. Unless you're willing to learn a ton of required knowledge, you won't be able to do it. If you just want filesharing, you could try a normal cloud storage like mega.nz. The rclone client provides advanced functionalities like mounting it to the local file system and other stuff, assuming that you are more or less a beginner when it comes to the deeper linux stuff, that should do the trick.